# Libfreenect not finding the Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, raspberrypi, libfreenect, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is sort of a follow up to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/47103/libfreenect-drivers-for-ros/) about libfreenect. I successfully got ROS installed on RaspberryPi (ARM) and compiled [freenect_stack](https://github.com/piyushk/freenect_stack) from @piyushk. I complete all of the [steps](http://ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack), but it can't find the Kinect:

```
[kevin@raspberrypi freenect_stack]$ rosrun freenect_camera freenect_node 
[ INFO] [1351981388.025719933]: Initializing nodelet with 1 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1351981396.302127503]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981399.320659202]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981402.339445895]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981405.356383634]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981408.375364319]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981411.394149012]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981414.413055699]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981417.431225405]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981420.453722998]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981423.472487689]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981426.493123329]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981429.516694892]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1351981432.538032515]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

Is there something else I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47409/libfreenect-not-finding-the-kinect/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-07**:
Hi Kevin - any suggestions around a couple of problems I've having building this:libfreenect: No definition of [libxmu-dev] for OS [debian]
freenect_launch: Missing resource pcl (I've installed libxmu-dev and freenect_camera: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version [] where to get log4cxx?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-07**:
and finally - MSG: gencfg_cpp on:Test.cfg
CMake Error at cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:66 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Thanks Mark

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-07**:
lsusb gives me  - "Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor" on the Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have any experience with the RaspberryPi. I am not sure how well libfreenect supports it. Can you check to see if lsusb gives a suitable output:

```
lsusb
```

lsusb should give an output similar to:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

Also, I am not sure which binaries inside libfreenect can be run on the pi, but hopefully atleast tiltdemo should work:

```
rosrun libfreenect tiltdemo
```

Let me know if the above work.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-11-10**:
No I only see the Motor and the Audio and Camera don't show up. There appears to be others having the same issue, so I has more to do with the RaspberryPi and nothing to do with your code. Some people are thinking it has to do with the RPi's USB implementation.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-20**:
Kevin - should you find a solution to this please let me know - am looking into it myself can covered/built from scratch all suggestions I've found thus far..... Thanks Mark

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-11-20**:
doing more research, many have built libfreenect for RPi, but I cannot find anyone that has really gotten it to work. RPi can see the kinect motor but not the camera and audio. I think this is a RPi issue and not anything else. RPi probably has a bandwidth issue on the USB bus. Still looking at it.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-20**:
Yep agreed - I'm getting the same issues as you...shall keep looking

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-25**:
Kevin - by way of an update. Received new 512Mb board this w/e and updated the firmware. Now I'm able to see motor, audio and camera. A quick test of the tiltdemo also works. How did you get freenect_stack to build?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-25**:
I get the following error: MSG: gencfg_cpp on:Test.cfg
CMake Error at cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:66 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:87 (gencfg_cpp)
CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)
when rosmake

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-11-25**:
I get the following error: MSG: gencfg_cpp on:Test.cfg
CMake Error at cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:66 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:87 (gencfg_cpp)
CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-11-25**:
Glad to hear you can see the camera now. I had no errors ... try opening a new question and posting the errors.